# Hashicorp vault ui is not accessible when running it through docker

Tags: docker, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to setup HashiCorp vault using docker. I am using MySql database for the storage. I created both MySql and Vault docker containers in same network using docker network.

**config.hcl**

```
ui = true

storage "mysql" {
  address = "localhost:3306"
  username = "root"
  password = "Test@12345"
  database = "vault"
}

listener "tcp" {
 address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
 tls_disable = "true"
 }
```

**MySql Container:**

```
docker run --name vault-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Test@12345 -d --network vault_network  mysql:latest
```

**Vault Container:**

```
docker run  -p 8200:8200 -e 'VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG={"backend": {"file": {"path": "/Users/jaddap2/vault/config.hcl"}}, "default_lease_ttl": "168h", "max_lease_ttl": "720h"}'  \
 --cap-add=IPC_LOCK --network vault_network  vault server
```

When I try to access the vault using http://127.0.0.1:8200/ui I get the following error

[image: vault error]

Comment: are they running? can you check status of the containers?

Comment: @hariK Yes, I can login into individual containers

Comment: can you change bind-address to `address = "0.0.0.0:8200"` and try?

Comment: @hariK I tried it, didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vault Docker container runs in dev mode by default as per it's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/hashicorp/docker-vault/blob/master/0.X/Dockerfile).

So, passing `server` argument won't make any different. You can simply run just `vault`. Then you'll be able to access the UI. But during the dev mode, it runs on memory.

```
docker run  -p 8200:8200 -e 'VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG={"backend": {"file": {"path": "/tmp/config.hcl"}}, "default_lease_ttl": "168h", "max_lease_ttl": "720h"}'  \
 --cap-add=IPC_LOCK --network vault_network vault
```

Comment: Ah. That's a bummer. Your command works except I get access denied for file path